# Windows 10 not recognizing speakers from a HDMI switch

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, hdmi, speakers

I have windows 10, xbox One, and nintendo switch all connected to a 5-to-1 HDMI switch. The audio out is connected to external speakers using a standard 3.5mm headphone jack (not optical cable) from the hdmi switch.

When I play the xbox or nintendo switch, the audio works fine from the speakers. But in my windows 10 laptop, it does not detect the speakers so I cannot pick it to make the audio come out from it. However if I plugin in any headphones on the laptop directly, those get detected and I can hear from them.

Anyone know what I can do to troubleshoot this?

[image]

```
Windows 10 Home 64-bit.
Dell Inc. XPS 15 9570
Version 10.0.19041 Build 19041
Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630
GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design, NVIDIA compatible
Realtek Audio
```

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have selected the TV as the audio device?

Comment: yes, the laptop is also displaying to the TV in terms of video, from the HDMI switch, so the connection is working. I'm guessing the problem is windows 10 is not routing the audio into the HDMI out of the laptop.

Comment: You need to make sure that the audio output on the laptop is sent to the laptop's HDMI port

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Xbox and Nintendo Switch do not have any audio devices, except that of the TV, which I presume the speakers are connected to.  Your PC has the potential for multiple audio devices, including, the speakers built-into the device itself.  So my question again is, have you selected the output audio to the TV, thus allowing the TV to be the audio source for the device?

Comment: @sawdust, I checked the audio playback devices, but HDMI is not listed in there.

Comment: @ramhound, the TV is actually just a monitor without speakers, and there is also external speakers connected to the hdmi switch. However I the speakers is not recognized as an option in windows 10, so I cannot select it, nor is HDMI an option as a audio play back device.

Comment: Add details to your post: laptop model and video adapter.  E.G. the Nvidia control panel has an option for enabling audio over HDMI

Comment: I added a picture of my playback devices and hardware specs. Also is there a article for that nvidia setting?

Comment: The audio and video subsystems are separate in a PC.  The HDMI port is under the video subsystem control.  You have to explicitly redirect the audio over to the video subsystem.  See https://www.nvidia.com/content/Control-Panel-Help/vLatest/en-us/mergedProjects/nvdsp/Set_Up_Digital_Audio.htm and https://www.nvidia.com/content/Control-Panel-Help/vLatest/en-us/mergedProjects/nvdsp/To_set_up_digital_audio_on_your_graphics_card.htm

Comment: I checked my nvidia control panel, and only "3d settings" shows there. "Display" is not. I think that is because the laptop screen is done by the integrated cpu. https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/121892/no-display-tab-in-nvidia-control-panel/

Comment: Seems like you need updated BIOS (1.15.1) and Windows drivers.  See https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-9570-not-using-Nvidia-GPU-BIOS-related-bug/td-p/6212789